# How can we force Isabelle to reveal to us what rule it's applying in the background in Isar when a proof starts?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving, hol

I was trying to prove:

```
lemma
  shows "¬ ev (Suc 0)"
```

I did:

```
lemma
  shows "¬ ev (Suc 0)"
proof (rule notI)
  assume "ev (Suc 0)"
  then show False 
  proof
```

and it gave me really pretty goals:

```
proof (state)
goal (2 subgoals):
 1. Suc 0 = 0 ⟹ False
 2. ⋀n. ⟦Suc 0 = Suc (Suc n); ev n⟧ ⟹ False
```

that could probably make my proof readable.

It seems it applied some sort of cases in the background. But when I wrote cases the proof finished immediately instead of showing the above rule inversion cases explicitly. See:

```
lemma
  shows "¬ ev (Suc 0)"
proof (rule notI)
  assume "ev (Suc 0)"
  then show False 
  proof (cases)
```

which shows:

```
proof (state)
goal:
No subgoals!
```

which means I can just place a `qed`.

How can I figure out exactly what (introduction?) rules Isar is doing automatically in Isabelle?

Comment: From Section 6.4.2 in Isar-ref: "Unless given explicitly by the user, the default initial method is standard, which subsumes at least rule or its classical variant rule. These methods apply a single standard elimination or introduction rule according to the topmost logical connective involved. There is no separate default terminal method. Any remaining goals are always solved by assumption in the very last step." I am not certain if there is an easy way to get the name of the fact though.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment to your question, in your case, `proof` boils down to `proof rule`. The `rule` method (without any parameters) applies some fitting introduction/elimination rule. You can find out which one it is using the `rule_trace` attribute:

```
    using [[rule_trace]] apply rule
```

(or you could have done `declare [[rule_trace]]` globally somewhere above or `note [[rule_trace]]` in your Isar proof)

This says

```
    proof (prove)
    goal (2 subgoals):
     1. Suc 0 = 0 ⟹ False
     2. ⋀n. Suc 0 = Suc (Suc n) ⟹ ev n ⟹ False 
    rules:
        ev ?a ⟹ (?a = 0 ⟹ ?P) ⟹ (⋀n. ?a = Suc (Suc n) ⟹ ev n ⟹ ?P) ⟹ ?P
```

so it doesn't give you the name, unfortunately. But it is clear that this rule must come from the `inductive` command, because you didn't prove it yourself. If you do a `print_theorems` command right after the `inductive` command, you find that this is the theorem `ev.cases`, which is also the one that the `cases` method uses (except that the `cases` method also does some postprocessing simplification of the goal, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921839/why-cant-i-make-my-cases-explicit-in-isabelle-when-the-proof-is-already-complet/61929907#61929907)).

The `inductive` command registers the `ev.cases` rule as an `elim?` rule, which means that the automation will not use it, but if you do something like `apply rule`, it will be considered.